# Add buttons to DatePicker control in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

In my application am using Datepicker control to select date from the calender. I want to integrate OK and CANCEL buttons to the calender. so that user can select date and click OK or user can click CANCEL to close the calender. suggest me best way to implement this functionality in .NET WPF.

If not, which third party control is best to add OK and CANCEL buttons to Datepicker?

Comment: @Naresh, Have you tried this article? [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126762/A-couple-of-tricks-when-using-the-standard-WPF-NET)

Answer (score 1):

> Sample for buttons in DatePicker

```
<Grid>
    <DatePicker x:Name="StartDate" SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate}" Height="40"  Width="120" >
        <DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="PART_Root">
                                <CalendarItem Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}" Name="PART_CalendarItem" Style="{TemplateBinding Calendar.CalendarItemStyle}" />
                                <Button Content="Ok" Click="OKClicked" Margin="0,0,0,2"/>
                                <Button Content="Cancel" Click="CancelClicked"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
    </DatePicker>
</Grid>
```